# Is it ok to do this change of variable in integration: let $x = x - 1$

Tags: calculus, integration, notation, proof-writing

In integrals like $\int \sqrt{x-1}\,dx$, is it ok to make  this change of variable in integration: "let $x = x - 1$"?

It looks sketchy — like saying, let 5 = 4.

Comment: You can do that. It's not a good practice though.

Comment: Ok, thanks John.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can let $u=x-1$. $x$ is never equal to $x-1$.

Comment: Ok, agreed.  Quick follow-up question to this:  It is an integral on the real line, with integrand that is an even function, say, |x| dx.  Can I just instead compute twice the integral of x dx, on the positive half line, 0 to infinity, because of even function symmetry, or should I really be using a change of variable for the case of improper integrals?  I don't think change of variable is necessary here, but just thought I'd ask.  Thanks,

Comment: If you have an even function, yes you can compute twice the integral of one side.

Comment: Ok, got it.  Thanks, @avid19.

Comment: If you want to thank me, hit the checkmark to the left. :)

Comment: Ok, done, @avid19 :-)

Answer (score 2):

> Is it ok to do this change of variable in integration: let $x = x - 1$

Certainly you may, if you do so *carefully*.
$$\begin{align}
g(x)+\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \operatorname d x
 & \;=\; g(x)+\int_{a}^{b} f(x-1) \operatorname d (x-1)
\\[1ex] & \;=\; g(x)+\int_{a+1}^{b+1} f(x-1) \operatorname d x
\end{align}$$

Notice, when we do this we may only so change the variable bound within the integration's scope.

It is probably *safer* to substitute with a different variable name though. (Less confusing.)

$$\begin{align}
g(x)+\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \operatorname d x
 & \;=\; g(u-1)+\int_{a}^{b} f(u-1) \operatorname d (u-1)
\\[1ex] & \;=\; g(u-1)+\int_{a+1}^{b+1} f(u-1) \operatorname d u
\end{align}$$

Notice: here we *can* change the variable outside the integration scope.

You might more often see written out as:

$$\begin{align}
\text{ Let } x & = u-1 & \therefore \mathrm d x = \mathrm d u
\\[2ex] g(x)+\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \operatorname d x
 & \;=\; g(u-1)+\int_{a+1}^{b+1} f(u-1) \operatorname d u
\end{align}$$